# Why should we distinguish between clause elements and word classes? Is that important?

Tags: grammar

The clause elements and word classes. I've searched everywhere for a well explained answer for my question. Yet, I still have no idea about the correct answer.

Comment: Are you asking about the contrast between word categories (parts of speech) like noun, verb, adjective and functions like subject, object modifier, and so on?

Comment: Why should we distinguish between body parts and garments? Do I really need to learn the words *glove* and *shoe* and *hat*? How is that different from just saying *hand* and *foot* and *head*? Is that important? I've searched everywhere and literally not a single website in the world has a well-explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

Word classes are not the same as clause elements. The Clause elements are Subject, Verb and Object. The Verb and Subject are sometimes known as the predicate when together. Word classes are in the groupings of Adjective, Verb and Noun. These then go into subgroups of: evaluative, comparative and superlative adjectives; stative, dynamic and auxiliary verbs; concrete and abstract nouns. This is why we need to differentiate between clause elements and word classes.

Comment: Actually, Ethan, the subject is not part of the predicate, which consists of the verb plus any complements and adjuncts that be present. Incidentally, there are other functions such as 'complement', 'modifier', 'marker' 'predicator' and 'head'.

Answer (score 0):

Word classes (noun, verb, adjective) describe what a word does in relation to other words, while clause elements (subject, object, complement) describe how the different parts of a sentence interact. As you can see demonstrated [here](http://babelnet.sbg.ac.at/themepark/grammar/clauseelements.htm), clause elements are defined much more broadly than word classes and can be filled by a wide variety of word and phrase constructs.

In essence, sentences/clauses are constructed out of clause elements which are constructed out of individual words, as defined by word classes. They describe two different "levels" of the grammar of an utterance.